# Allow Camera Access for Specific Site on Chrome Android Version

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, android

I created a project for work where you can scan barcodes via a mobile browser and do additional stuff like directly print the label, get information about the item and other things. The scanning process works very good but one thing bothers me:

The "Allow Camera Access" popup. I want to disable it, but only for this specific host, not for all pages. I google but the only solutions I found did not apply to the android (mobile) version, only to the desktop version of chrome.

My Question is now, how can I set up chrome on android, to automatic allow camera access for specific hosts (whitelist)?

Comment: You cannot. But if you use HTTPS, the browser will only ask for permissions once and remember it afterwards.

Comment: Good point, but the service runs already at https, but I still have to allow it each time. Maybe it is because it is a self signed certificate for the local domain?

Comment: Oh, yes. You have to have a proper trusted certificate for Chrome to stop asking for permissions.

Comment: And there we go, another dictation for the user. I mean the security about this behaviour is totaly fine and I agree with it as a default by 100%, but why is there never a option for the actual user to turn it off. A simple switch wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Protect the stupidest of the users, I assume :/

Comment: Yeah, and scares off developers/users who actually creates additional value to their product (chrome browser software)